# Red Squares in RDKit?

Tags: software, cheminformatics

I'm newish to RDKit and couldn't find an answer to this online.  The following is a minimal representation of how I drew a molecule

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw as Draw
from rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors import CalcMolFormula

# .. read mol_a from file... then
print(repr(mol_a))
<rdkit.Chem.rdchem.Mol object at 0x7fd5c5494dc0>

print(CalcMolFormula(mol_a))
C4H11N

Draw.MolToImageFile(mol_a, 'pic.png')
```

Here is what I get:

[image: Chemical drawing]

What are those red boxes?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.7.3

I had three semesters of college chemistry about a decade ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In your 3d data some atoms have the same coordinates.

If all coordinates are singular like here

```
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem as Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

mb1 ='''
     RDKit          3D

 16 15  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.4420   -0.8874   -0.7989 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.3758    0.0725   -0.4996 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.9154    1.1745    0.2995 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7376   -0.6096    0.1788 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.9820    0.2624    0.3084 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.0693   -1.6891   -1.4463 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.8570   -1.3405    0.1088 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.2571   -0.4005   -1.3461 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.1723    1.9659    0.4378 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.2580    0.8409    1.2857 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.7617    1.6439   -0.2155 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4357   -0.9719    1.1698 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.0275   -1.4907   -0.4080 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.8280    1.0937    1.0028 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.2816    0.6703   -0.6627 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8161   -0.3344    0.6923 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0
  2  3  1  0
  2  4  1  0
  4  5  1  0
  1  6  1  0
  1  7  1  0
  1  8  1  0
  3  9  1  0
  3 10  1  0
  3 11  1  0
  4 12  1  0
  4 13  1  0
  5 14  1  0
  5 15  1  0
  5 16  1  0
M  END'''
```

You get a pic without the red box.

```
mol1 = Chem.MolFromMolBlock(mb1, removeHs=False)
Draw.MolToImage(mol1)
```

[image]

If I give the H on position 15 the coordinates from the C from position 5

```
mb2 ='''
     RDKit          3D

 16 15  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
   -1.4420   -0.8874   -0.7989 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.3758    0.0725   -0.4996 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.9154    1.1745    0.2995 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7376   -0.6096    0.1788 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.9820    0.2624    0.3084 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.0693   -1.6891   -1.4463 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.8570   -1.3405    0.1088 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.2571   -0.4005   -1.3461 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.1723    1.9659    0.4378 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.2580    0.8409    1.2857 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.7617    1.6439   -0.2155 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.4357   -0.9719    1.1698 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.0275   -1.4907   -0.4080 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.8280    1.0937    1.0028 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.9820    0.2624    0.3084 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.8161   -0.3344    0.6923 H   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0
  2  3  1  0
  2  4  1  0
  4  5  1  0
  1  6  1  0
  1  7  1  0
  1  8  1  0
  3  9  1  0
  3 10  1  0
  3 11  1  0
  4 12  1  0
  4 13  1  0
  5 14  1  0
  5 15  1  0
  5 16  1  0
M  END'''
```

you get the red box

[image]